# Migrate to asp.net mvc control implementing IDataSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given the situation:

A user control implementing IDataSource. It has a textbox or two, and a button. Now, when put on any page and adding a GridView with the DataSource being that control, presto you have a grid with filters .

How should I go about implementing this scenario in asp.net MVC ?
Any suggestions ?

Should I give more details ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've stumbled across one of the defining differences between ASP.NET MVC and WebForms.  You can't do this sort of RAD drag-and-drop type stuff with MVC (right now).  You'd need to basically build your own GridView View and stick in some filtering actions (with jQuery or something for clientside filtering).  The user control could be made into a "partial view" in this case.

However, if this is the sort of application that you do often, I don't think that switching to MVC will give you many benefits (given the limited context information that you've supplied).

Your question is "How", but I think the more important question is "Why".